# How I can work with (Laravel voyager) and (Vue SPA)?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, voyager

Please I want some help about and Issue in My **Laravel and Vue SPA** Project.

I'm using **(Vue SPA)** and **Laravel Voyager** for Admin.

The problem when I want to go to the admin panel using : **/admin** the panel did not show.

This is my **Routes/web.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/{any}', 'CodeCommunityController@index')->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

Please help guys and thank you.

Comment: try moving the "admin" route above the "any" this will override the "/any"

Comment: How i can do that my friend can you change it for me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, all I did is move the admin route above the any* route.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
Route::get('/{any}', 'CodeCommunityController@index')->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: Still have one question please when I'm login to admin panel it rederect me to home page (/) normally should redirect me to the (admin) Dashboard.

Comment: you can see this issue, check it here https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1729